# Multiselect display counter in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

next to the Search Results: I want to add a number of counts of the list

I need to display number of items selected in the multi-select list next to the `Total Selected Counts` and I'm using `<apex:outputText >` but not sure how to display the counter next to it?

```
 <td>
    <apex:selectList value="{!RightSelectedList}" multiselect="true"   style="width:100%" size="10"  >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!RightOptionList}"   />
    </apex:selectList><apex:outputText >Total Selected Counts:</apex:outputText>
</td>
```

Comment: Do you want the number selected the last time the page was saved (do-able with Visualforce) or do you want the number currently selected in the UI i.e. when the user has changed the selection but not yet saved the page (that required JavaScript)?

Comment: The last part, selected in the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I able to achieve:

Apex:

```
public string RightSelectedListCount()
{
    return RightSelectedList.size();
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
{!RightSelectedListCount()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to count and display the selected options in HTML using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/):

```
<html>
<body>
<select class="selectMarker" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Flowers</option>
    <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
    <option>Trees</option>
    <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
    <option>Grass</option>
    <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div class="countMarker"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
    function updateCount() {
        var n = $('.selectMarker option:selected').length;
        $('.countMarker').html(n);
    }
    $('.selectMarker').change(function() {
        updateCount();
    });
    updateCount();
})(jQuery.noConflict());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

To convert this to Visualforce, just copy the script content and use the `styleClass` attribute on the Visualforce tags where `class` is used above on the HTML elements.

Comment: hmm... i am not sure if this is the right way of doing and since I already have list when the user adds in the multi-select, what i'm looking a way to display the list.count in the visualforce page... it will be much easier then using jquery which i think its not overkill in my opinion.

Comment: you see I already know what has been selected `RightSelectedList` so what I need on the apex side to `count` and display on the VFP, thats what i am looking a way to display the value

Comment: @AbuHamzah The above works when the page is first opened and also works immediately the selection is changed. Not sure why you want the count, but if you only calculate it when the page is opened and the list is editable then the count will be wrong immediately the user edits it and will only be correct after a save and a re-opening of the page. But to compute the count in Apex (avoiding jQuery) you can split the picklist value on the separator for multi-select picklists which is a semi-colon and take the size of the resulting array.

Comment: I will post you the screen shot to make more clear

Comment: I have updated my question with an image to give more context of my question. - thanks.

Comment: @AbuHamzah OK. Personally I would still do it with jQuery, but you could do it in Apex and re-render.